# How to Resolve Warning about Key Stored in Legacy trusted.gpg Keyring in apt-get Update?

Tags: apt, updates, repository, gnupg

I'm running into an issue while updating my package lists on Ubuntu. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, the process completes successfully, but it ends with a warning message about a key being stored in a legacy `trusted.gpg` keyring. Here's the specific warning I'm receiving:

```
W: https://deb.beekeeperstudio.io/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

I understand that this is related to the way GPG keys are stored for verifying the authenticity of packages from repositories, but I'm not sure on how to address this warning.

From what I understood, the key for the Beekeeper Studio repository should be moved from `trusted.gpg` to the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` directory.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I safely move the key to the correct location to resolve this warning?
2. Is it safe to delete the key from the old location, and if so, how can I do that?
3. Will deleting or moving the key affect my ability to receive updates from the Beekeeper Studio repository?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to install beekeeper-studio, flowed by the answers to your question:

Add the GPG key:

```
curl -fSsL https://deb.beekeeperstudio.io/beekeeper.key | sudo gpg --dearmor | 
sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/beekeeper-studio.gpg > /dev/null
```

Add the APT repository:

```
echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/beekeeper.gpg] https://deb.beekeeperstudio.io stable main' |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/beekeeper-studio.list
```

Install the package:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install beekeeper-studio
```

> How can I safely move the key to the correct location to resolve this warning?

You can move the key from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` to `/usr/share/keyrings/`. The key should be **dearmored** (Not an ASCII armored key). (First command), but it is better to grab the key from remote server, maybe the key has been expired and moving the key will be useless. Here is how to move the certificate locally:

```
cat /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/beekeeper.key | sudo gpg --dearmor | 
sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/beekeeper-studio.gpg > /dev/null
```

> Is it safe to delete the key from the old location, and if so, how can I do that?

It is safe, and it is recommended to delete the old key using `apt-key` or `rm`. Use `ls /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` to see the exact file name.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/beekeeper.key
```

> Will deleting or moving the key affect my ability to receive updates from the Beekeeper Studio repository?

Moving the key (or updating) is necessary to set up your APT-repository correctly. You will be able to receive the package update.